# WebStorm/PhpStorm + Git integration: "Same" vs "Latest" repository version

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I am new to Git, so sorry if this is a stupid question, but what is the different between the following two options in the `git` submenu of the context menu that comes up on right clicking a file in WebStorm/PhpStorm (in the Project sidebar)

- Compare with *same* repository version
- Compare with *latest* repository version

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/comparing-file-versions.html. Same version is the version you last synchronized to. Shows current local changes since last update. Comparing to the latest repository version may show additional changes, if file was changed in the repository since the last update.

Comment: Thanks for the link. if you post this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Comparing file versions](http://jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/comparing-file-versions.html) help section.

- *Same* version is the version you last synchronized to. Shows current local changes since last update.
- Comparing to the *latest* repository version may show additional changes, if the file was changed in the repository since the last update.